# I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 (using something else) and now I cannot boot windows 8

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

Hello everyone I'm new to Ubuntu so I probably messed something up. When I installed Ubuntu on my windows 8 hp laptop it did not give me the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows so I installed it using the something else option.

I think I may have messed up during the partitioning but I'm not sure.

When I turned on the PC it at first directly booted up Ubuntu without showing me the grub screen, eventually I was able to get the grub screen to appear but it does not recognize windows. I ran boot repair and I was given this url : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6701216/ .
Boot-repair did not solve my problem.

Thanks for any help guys I really want to be able to run windows alongside Ubuntu and access the files that are in windows.

Comment: ..using _something else_ should be backed up with ideas about partitioning.. mbr/gpt tables, basic/dynamic disks/volumes, etc. and so dual booting with preinstalled Win8 will need bit more work than it used to with the previous versios..

Answer (score 0):

You could try `grub-install` and then `grub-update` to have GRUB check for currently installed operating systems.

I'm not sure I can be much help without knowing what you did in the partitioner when you installed Ubuntu, but try those two commands and see if it works.